# Event on adding a related object

Tags: lightning, event, lightning-events

So this below is the standard modal for adding a team member:

[image: standard modal]

I'm almost sure that when you click "Save" an event is fired and you can catch that event and handle it. The point is I can't find the documentation or the example anymore. Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone reading , the event I was looking for is this one:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:recordSaveSuccess/documentation

Answer (score 2):

I have used the Google Lightning Inspector plug in. It allows you to record the app, component, and unhandled events that occur when performing an action. Some of the events also have visibility to the parameters that you can access when handling that event. Below is a link for more info:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/inspector_intro.htm